# Can someone explain C pointers

Tags: c, pointers

Can someone explain why v[2] ends up having the value -3, instead of being empty, or 25 for that matter?

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main ()
 {
   int v[5];
   int *z = &v[0];
   *z=12;
   z++;
   *z=16;
   z++;
   *z=-3;
   z++;
   *z=25;

   printf ("%d", v[2]);
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain why you believe the result could be 25?

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm new to this site, sorry

Comment: @GregHewgill well, it's the last value z is being set to, so why not that rather than -3?

Comment: Hint: For a pointer variable `z`, `z++` assumes `z` points at part of an array and means to change the pointer to point at the next object in that array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int v[5];
    int *z = &v[0]; // z points to v[0]
    *z=12; // v[0] = 12
    z++;   // z points to v[1] now
    *z=16; // v[1] = 16
    z++;   // z points to v[2] now
    *z=-3; // etc
    z++;   // etc
    *z=25; // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting -3 everytime since that is the 3rd element in your array (Remember, 0 counts as the first array slot). Each time you increment Z (Z++), you point to the next available slot. *Z = some_Number simply assigns that value to the pointed array slot.

```
        printf ("%d", v[3]); //should give you 25
```

Answer (score 0):

`z` is a pointer to an array of integers, this piece of code:

`*z=12;` is equivalent to `v[0]=12;` because z is being dereferenced.

However, you are not incrementing `*z`, which is the dereferenced pointer to `v[0]` and would result in `v[0]`'s value incrementing.

Instead, you're incrementing `z`, which is the pointer's own value - the address of `v[0]`.

`z` is a pointer, and when you increment it here: `z++;` the result is essentially the next element in the array `v[0]`.

In your code, the resulting array will be filled like so:

`*z=12;` = `v[0]=12;`

`z++;`

`*z=16;` = `v[1]=16;`

and so on.